# Center content if text becomes bigger

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, layout

i have this sample xaml:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
             HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
  <StackLayout BackgroundColor="LightBlue">
    <Label Text="ABC"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
    <Label Text="L"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
  </StackLayout>
  <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" />
  <StackLayout BackgroundColor="LightGreen">
    <Label Text="ABC"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
    <Label Text="C"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
  </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

which produces this output:
[image: Center ok]
But if one of the four lables becomes bigger there are not centered anymore:
[image: Bigger label]

My goal is the following layout, which depends on the biggest label:
[image: Center]

I'm a beginner. So i hope somebody could help me with the correct layout.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StackLayout really isn't the best choice here, because it occupies the size dynamically (i.e. depending on its content). What's the better approach here is to use Xamarin.Forms' [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid) layout.

This way, you can have a grid with 3 columns. Then, you will set your [ColumnDefinitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.grid.columndefinitions?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Grid_ColumnDefinitions)'s width to star (*). Like you can see in the [Rows and columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid#rows-and-columns) section, setting the column's width to star means that:

> Star – leftover row height or column width is allocated proportionally (a number followed by * in XAML).

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" /> <!-- Blue StackLayout wrapper -->
    <BoxView Grid.Column="1" /> <!-- Red BoxView -->
    <StackLayout Grid.Column="2" /> <!-- Green StackLayout wrapper -->
</Grid>
```

Basically, you will have divided the whole screen width to 3 equal parts, each resulting in an 33,3(3) % of the screen. Then, you can align the elements in the container as you wish.